# Display multiple push notifications like multiple SMS on Android?

Tags: android

I am able to show total push notifications count on top bar but still looking for displaying each notification on top bar. Currently, it shows total count and last notification received. I want to show all notifications like total SMS count and each SMS displayed in Android. Immediate response will be highly appreciated. Thanks
[image: Total Messages count and each message listed]

Comment: I want to display all push notifications like all message count and message displayed in above screen shot.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup somehow a counter that will be your notification ID. If the id is different on each notification, you'll be able to show it all on the notification bar. More on Notifications [here](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: Hi Ze, Thanks for prompt response. Here is screen shot of code and notification. Thanks  https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gcnbgmsaiaqptd/code.png?dl=0    https://www.dropbox.com/s/2t4u5drof2y6las/totalNotifications.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi @WasifHamdani. You have to make the trick on the last line. the first parameter of the method `notify` is the notification id. If you put somewhere a variable that you increment on each call of your method, and pass it on the `notify` method, you'll have one notification for each call.

Comment: Hi Ze, In that case separate notification receive for each call. I don't want to generate separate notification for every call. If a notification available on top bar, then for every new notification, only notification message/text display next to existing notification text. did you get a chance to look at the screen shots attached? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Let me see if I got that. You want to update your notification appending new text to it, right?

Comment: Yes, appending new text to existing notification.